# What is the equivalent of this SQL statement in Linq?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, projection

I need to port this SQL statement to LINQ:

```
SELECT f.ID as IdFlight, 
       Tarif * 1 as Tarif, 
       f.Time, f.TimeOfArrival, 
       sl.Name as FromLoc, 
       sl.Country as FromCountry, 
       sl.Airport as FromAirport,
       dl.Name as ToLoc, 
       dl.Country as ToCountry, 
       dl.Airport as ToAirport 
FROM Flights as f 
    INNER JOIN Locations as sl ON sl.ID = f.ID_Source  
    INNER JOIN Locations as dl ON dl.ID = f.ID_Destination 
    INNER JOIN FlightsTarifs as ftf ON f.Id = ftf.IDFlight 
WHERE f.ID_Destination =30005 AND f.Time <= DATEADD(day,4,'2018/05/24 00:00') 
AND f.Time >= '2018/05/24 00:00' ORDER By f.Time, Tarif
```

My attempt in Linq:

```
IQueryable qinfo = from f in context.Flights
                   join sl in context.Locations on f.Id_Source equals sl.ID
                   join dl in context.Locations on f.Id_Destination equals dl.ID
                   join ftf in context.FlightsTarifs on f.ID equals ftf.IDFlight
                   where (f.Id_Source == aFormUser.FlightSrcID)
                   where (f.Id_Destination == aFormUser.FlightDestID)
                   where (f.Time.Date >= aFormUser.DepartureDate.Date)
                   where (f.Time.Date <= aFormUser.DepartureDate.Date.AddDays(4))
                   orderby f.Time, ftf.Tarif
                   select new {f.ID, ftf.Tarif, f.Time, f.TimeOfArrival,
                               sl.Name, sl.Country, sl.Airport,
                               dl.Name, dl.Country, dl.Airport  };
```

I have some problems to solve now:

1. Since I am joining the table flights with the table locations twice, in order to get the name of source and of destination locations, doing this in LinQ causes a compiler error, that says dl.Name, dl.Country, dl,Airport are anonymous types and they would end having same name as the others sl.Name, sl.Country, sl.Airport.
2. I cannot use the "As" expression as I do in Sql or is there any Equivalent one in Linq?
3. I cannot multiply Tarif by the number of passengers while i am in the linq query, while it does not allow me to do this.

Comment: I would ask why you want to take perfectly good sql and move it to the application layer. Why not turn your query into a stored procedure and separate the layers in your application? To me this seems like the wrong direction to migrate sql code.

Comment: I was exactly thinking to write a comment like Sean. I totally agree with him. Such a queries has to be stayed in stored procedure and bringing them to do application layer is some sort of anti-pattern.

Comment: Do I have to move it to a stored procedure because it is a complex query and it cannot be done with linq? I don't see how this breaks the pattern. You have to do some queries in complex applications, do you mean that the pattern is violatedevery time one performs queries in MVC? Beside that I am not sure Ican use stored procedure from MVC. Will the DBContext take care of calling any storedprocedure? Do I have to make a EF Migration in order to do so?

Comment: I am not suggesting that any pattern is broken. I am saying that a layered application is much more supportable in the long run and that one of those layers is the data layer. To accomplish this means your data manipulation needs to be removed from the application. Moving from a query to linq means your data manipulation is more tightly coupled with the application. Here is a great article discussing layering at a high level. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ee658109(v=pandp.10)

Comment: Anti-Pattern does not mean breaking the patterns, based on Wikipedia, it means: An anti-pattern is a common response to a recurring problem that is usually ineffective and risks being highly counterproductive.
Again, as Sean mentioned it is just a suggestion and does not mean you're breaking rules, but it is a good practice to have more clear layering.

Comment: @user1238784 if you created proper relations and navigation properties between the entities you wouldn't have to join anything. The ORM itself will generate JOINs based on the relations. LINQ isn't a replacement to SQL and entities are *not* tables

Comment: @user1238784 your `Flight` class should have two `Location`-typed properties, Origin and Destination (we dont' call it source in the travel industry). If you have multiple fares or taxes you should have *collection* properties for your Fare, Tax classes. This will allow you to write eg `context.Flights.Where(flight=>flight.Origin.AirportCode="LAX" and flight.Destination.AirportCode="LHR").ToArray();`

Comment: @Panagiotis my flight class is taken from the database 1-1. In the database I cannot store typed fields. That's why I have an IdOrigin and an IDDestination.

Comment: @user1238784 *don't* take it from the database 1-1. That's a very big mistake. You *already* have multiple entities - Flight, Location, FlightTarrif. You *don't* need the joins, just add properties and relations to your classes.

Comment: @user1238784 otherwise imagine what a mess that query would become if I asked for overnight long-haul flights. Without credit-card fees (ie a Fee with an OB code). 50 of them, ordered by ascending total. BTW that's a typical query used to retrieve flight results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the aliases with the `new` object initializer with the code below, which will also support multiplying the tarif:

```
select new {
    f.ID,
    Tarif = ftf.Tarif * 1, // Alias and multiply by your number
    f.Time,
    f.TimeOfArrival,
    SourceName = sl.Name, // Alias
    SourceCountry = sl.Country, // Alias
    SourceAirport = sl.Airport, // Alias
    DestName = dl.Name, // Alias
    DestCountry = dl.Country, // Alias
    DestAirport = dl.Airport // Alias
};
```

Just to provide a few more details in case others stumble on this, the root cause is that the code was using the `new` keyword to define an anonymous type with an object initializer that ran into multiple conflicts trying to define the anonymous class (multiple properties with same inferred name, and then unable to name property from expression when tarif was multiplied).

By explicitly naming the properties with conflicts, the compiler no longer had to infer the naming that generated the conflicts.

More: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx

The link above has some additional examples on how to use the object initializer with anonymous types.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called **Projection**, you have to select new anonymous type or alias according to your requirement.

**Sample:**

```
var result = data.Select( x => new { FieldName = x.Property } );
```