# Entity Framework Query Related Data with same column name by Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm new to Visual Studio and EF Core. I want to write a query from `table x` that needs to join to tables `a` and `b`. Both of `a` and `b` have columns with name `Name`. How can I do a thing like this?

```
var ItemList = db.TableX
               .Include(itemx => itemx.TableA.Name as AName)
               .Include(itemx => itemx.TableB.Name as BName)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: aren't x,a and b three different entities? If yes, then clarify on what property of x you want to join . If they are not seperate entities then please, post the structure of X at least or give some more details.

Comment: @Sumitraj every 3 tables are entities. How can I specify what property from each table?

Comment: i am just asking, you want to join a and b on name column , the same way how do u plan to join [X and A] or [X and B] . It's best to give sample example. It will help to understand and solve.

Comment: this article solve your problem 
http://debuxing.com/entity-framewok-join-tables-example-c/

Comment: You need to use Projection https://stackoverflow.com/a/50512006/6527049

Comment: Is there a mapping made between these 3 tables? Are you using refference ids?